# CSS column extending to the bottom of the page with scroll

Tags: css

I have a web page with the following templates

ROW1
COL1 COL2 COL3

Now, I want COL1 COL2 COL3 extending to the bottom of the browser, with vertical scroll bars when the content in COLs is too long.

How can I implement this in CSS3?

Existing style is:

```
body,html {
   height:100%;
}

.col1 .col2 .col3 {
   min-height: 100%;
   overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```

But the page is longer than the browser now and scroll does not work.

Comment: height:100% is a total junk in html styling. It doesnt work that way. The browser will render the element's height according to its content automatically. Can you try to remove all the height:'s and use height:40px (or any height that you want to use) and then set overflow-y:auto ?

Comment: The column height is unknown, and the browser should figure it out. An example is http://www.zeroblock.com/. But it seems they use jscrollpane and the height seems to be calculated and set by javascript. Can I implement this just using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a while, I think CSS might not solve the problem. My reasoning is following. Setting height 100%, which should calculating from parents. If no rows there, it get the number from body. However, if there is a row, there is no way to calculating the height just from the parent.

So I think javascript is needed to dynamically set the height in this case. And the following code works in my case now. Just get the window size and the top y-position of the content block, and set the height with the difference.

```
<script>
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
var h = $(window).height() - $('.col1').offset().top -10;
$('.col1').height(h);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vHkJ8/

How about this:

```
<style>
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    width: 30%;
    margin:0 1%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<div class="col1">1</div>
<div class="col2">2</div>
<div class="col3">3</div>
```

Comment: It seems that it breaks if adding a row above, since col3 is 100% of the browser, and adding the row, the total height is now exceeding the browser's height.

Comment: If you want a CSS only solution, you'd just make each row a percentage that adds up to 100% still, So row one is 25%, row two is 75%. If you want a fixed height for the inserted row, or a dynamic number of rows above, then JS is probably the easiest solution.